# How to reverse iteration once it reaches the end python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a hard time making an infinite loop where once my iteration ends it will simply iterate backwards

for example:

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        print(i, j)
```

would print:

```
(0,0), (0,1), (0,3), ... (4,4)
```

how can I modify this so that once it reaches (4, 4) it would simply

```
(0,0), (0,1), (0,3), ... (4,4), (4, 3), (4, 2), (4, 1), ... (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), ... (4, 4), ...
```

so its an infinite iteration. I can't find a way to do this I hope I can be guided to the right way to solve this. I am not allowed to use any import so I have to do this by loops I guess.

Comment: You could add all items that you print to a stack and when you are done pop every item from the stack again.

Comment: Or you could add more loops that just result in the same numbers but in a different order.

Comment: is there a way I could write this in a nested loop?

Comment: Yes, that would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

```py
import itertools
ourlist = [...]
for i in itertools.cycle(ourlist + ourlist[::-1]):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

@BoarGules and @chai answers are not what the OP wants, because they produce `..., (0, 0), (0, 0), ...` and `..., (4, 4), (4, 4), ....`

To get the desired output, you can use the following

```py
m = 5
t = (0, m, 1)
while True:
  for i in range(*t):
    for j in range(*t):
      if (i, j) == (t[1]-t[2], t[1]-t[2]): break
      print((i, j))
  t = (t[1]-t[2], t[0]-t[2], -t[2])
```

**Explanation**

The tuple `t` contains the arguments for `range()`. The idea is that everytime the two for loops finish, we must change the arguments of `range()` to go through the numbers backwards. That is achieved by the last line `t = (t[1]-t[2], t[0]-t[2], -t[2])` which will resonate between `(2, -1, -1)` and `(0, 3, 1)`.

Apart from that, we need to make sure that we do not print the "last" tuple twice. The `if` statement takes care of that, by not printing the last tuple. So, each `while` iteration will print either `(0, 0), (0, 1), ..., (4, 3)` or `(4, 4), (4, 3), ..., (0, 1)`.

**Note**: You can achieve the same result by modifying the answers by @BoarGules and @chai. However, this approach does not require you to store the an entire period of the pattern in memory, as is the case with @chai's answer and it does not repeat code.